# Rails filter search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a very simple filter in Rails using checkboxes. I have a `listing` model with a `category` attribute that gets filled out when a new listing is created.

These are the possible categories:

```
<% categories = ["All", "Bourbon", "Whiskey", "Scotch", "Japanese", "Irish", "Canadian"] %>
```

I have a form that loops over the categories and creates a checkbox for each

```
<%= form_tag(listings_path, method: :get) do %>
              <% categories.each do |category| %>
                <div class="category-option d-block mb-2">
                  <%= check_box_tag "#{category}", category.downcase %>
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    <%= category %>
                  </label>
                </div>
              <% end %>
              <%= submit_tag('Filter',class: 'inline-flex items-center justify-center px-5 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-black') %>
            <% end %>
```

My ultimate goal is to have the URL have a category param that lists all the selected categories like so:
`http://localhost:3000/listings?q=query&category=bourbon,scotch`

Currently, with my implementation, my URL looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/listings?Scotch=scotch&commit=Filter`

How I can make my form behave so I get the outcome I desire?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the checkbox with

```
<%= check_box_tag :category, category.downcase %>
```

This will return http://localhost:3000/listings?q=query&category=[bourbon,scotch]

So you access it in the controller using `params[:category]` and this is array of value that user has choose with checkbox

Comment: This works for the most part. However, my params read `category=whiskey&category=scotch` instead of `category=[bourbon,scotch]`

Comment: Sorry for my bad, yeah it will be `category=whiskey&category=scotch` in the URL, but it will be an array in your controller when you call `params[:category]`. I think it doesn't matter how it be in URL, as long as you can access it as an array in your controller.